# iText pdf links contain closing square bracket

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

i try to embed a link to an external website into a pdf-file, generated with iText.
Heres the code:

Phrase modul  = new Phrase ("some text");
Chunk www    = new Chunk ("www.arzneimittelinfoservice.de");
      www.setAction(new PdfAction(new URL("http://www.arzneimittelinfoservice.de")));
Phrase xref = new Phrase(www);
Phrase link = new Phrase("goto link: " + xref);
...

Problem: in the resulting pdf-doc the link referres to http://www.arzneimittelinfoservice.de**]**, I can't get rid of the closing square bracket.

Perhaps someone can help me with this.

Thanks, Frank

Comment: hello. if my answer corrected your problem, could you set the question to answered ? 
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying your code, i've got the following result :

> goto link:
>   [www.arzneimittelinfoservice.de]

adding the www chunk as such, i got the following result:

> goto link
>   :www.arzneimittelinfoservice.de

you do this by adding the chunck to the phrase, and not by converting it to string, which is what the "+" is doing in  the *"goto link: " + xref* part.

```
...   
Phrase link = new Phrase("goto link: ");
link.add(www);
```

Regards
Guillaume